Why do some sites (sometimes) have a lower amount of questions on the homepage?
Inspired by Are there actually hidden questions?, I decided to have a look at the different sites to see how many questions there actually are on the homepage. For most of the question lists pages like All Questions, you can actually choose between 15, 30 and 50.
Right now here on Meta.SE it's 48, which seems to be an age-old default. This is true for many other sites, but right now on Chess.SE there are only 47. On Meta Stack Overflow, it's much lower (currently 40, but Wayback Machine copies may go even lower). Something similar seems to happen with sites with a personalized homepage (the Interesting tab); Stack Overflow currently has 100 questions; Mathematics only 96 questions.
What's the reason behind this? An obvious candidate may be deleted questions, but we have a lot of those here on Meta.SE as well and we do have a 'full' homepage.
To quickly count the questions, you can execute $(".js-post-summary").length in your browser console.
